# Using USB barcode scanner in angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, barcode

I have an application in **Angular 10** and I would like to implement **USB barcode scanner input** (for example in **keyboard mode**). The problem is that I'm using package **ngx-barcodeput** where I need an input field which **should be active when barcodes is scanning**. How can I use something like ngx-barcodeput **without input field**? I would like to have my **scanner active all the time on the page** not only when I click on input field. Have any tips? I searched the web and I cannot find any another package which can be used for usb barcode scanners in angular apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code scans barcode from USB bacode scanner in angular application,

HTML file:

```
    <div class="container">
        <header><h1>My App title</h1></header>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" (window:keypress)="onKey($event)"  autofocus />
            <p>barcode: {{ barcode }}</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

app component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'barcode-scanner',
  templateUrl: './scan-barcode.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scan-barcode.component.css'],

})
export class ScanBarcodeComponent implements OnInit {
  barcode: string='';
  values: string[] =[];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onKey(event: any) {
    this.barcode=event.target.value;
}

}
```

See complete code here: https://github.com/saurabhku/ex-angular-barcode-scan